# How to get the STDDEV() of groups of items without the MIN() and MAX() of the group

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, standard-deviation

I have a table like

```
| id | user | bottle |  count |
| 1  | foo  | beer   |    2   |
| 2  | bar  | beer   |    5   |
| 3  | som1 | beer   |    6   |
| 4  | som2 | beer   |    4   |
| 5  | som1 | wine   |    1   |
```

etc.

How can I get the `STDDEV()` without the `MIN()` and `MAX()` value of `count` for each group(beer, wine, etc)?
i.e how do i get

```
| bottle |      stddev     |

|  beer  |stddev of 2 and 4|
```

?

Also how can I get the number of rows that a query like the above returns in total?

So far I've tried

```
SELECT STD(count) as stddev, bottle
FROM drinks WHERE count &lt; (
    SELECT MAX(count) FROM drinks)
              AND count &gt; (
    SELECT MIN(count) FROM drinks)
GROUP BY bottle;
```

but that works for the `MAX()` of the whole table and not only of the 
`GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation and a join to bring in the extreme values, then filter them out and calculate the standard deviation:

```
select bottle, STDEV(d.count)
from drd.inks d join
     (select bottle, MIN(count) as minc, MAX(count) as maxc
      from drinks
      group by bottle
     ) dsum
     on d.bottle = dsum.bottle and
        d.count not in (dsum.minc, dsum.maxc)
group by d.bottle
```